# CDemu won't run with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

Trying to run `cdemu` so I can write `.aax` file to a virtual cd, so that I can then extract to `.mp3`.  However, can't seem to get `cdemu` to run on Ubuntu 15.04.  I've used both the ppa and downloaded the source code to compile.  No joy.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Close voters, why is that off-topic?

Comment: Which PPA? https://launchpad.net/~cdemu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa has no Vivid packages. And give me the URL to download the source code.

Comment: CDemu **VHBA module** requires an old Kernel version *(kernel development headers >= 2.6.20)* that is not available in 15.04 making cdemu not work.